# Keep getting Nonetype has no attribute head

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This is the code that produces the error:

```
dict1 = {
  "requestId": "32",
  "records": {
    "totalRecords": 5,
    "currentPageSize": 5,
    "currentPageNumber": 1
  }
}

j3 = dict1.get("totalRecords")
j3.head()
```

Comment: did you mistype that?  is j3.head on another line?

Comment: `totalRecords` is in the sub-dictionary `records`.  It is not a direct member of `dict1`.

Comment: What on earth do you expect `.head()` to do and why?

Comment: j3 = dict1.get('records', {}).get('totalRecords')
please correct this line and tryt agian

Answer (score 0):

Your code to get total records needs to frist get "records like this:

```
j3 = dict1.get("records").get("totalRecords")
```

Its a nested dictionary so you need to get the dictionary containing it first.

You will still get an error with the head() function call as int does not have that function defined for it (the 5 is an int)